# Estructuras de Datos (C)

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

Buenas.

Estaba trabajando con el código de un programa y me ha surgido una duda respecto a las estructuras de datos. Tenemos estos dos casos, uno en el "programa.c" y otro en el "programa.h":

programa.c:

```
struct _estructura {
    /* El código aqui es indiferente */
};
```

programa.h:

```
typedef struct _estructura estructura;
```

Me gustaría saber la diferencia que hay en definir la estructura directamente en el programa.c y el caso anterior. ¿ Es decir, en el .c estamos declarando la estructura y la definimos en el .h ? Si alguien me lo pudiera aclarar...

Muchas gracias,
Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso se conoce como `pre-declaración`.

En el `.h` estás informando al compilador de que el símbolo `struct _estructura` es precisamente eso, una estructura de datos; no le indicas lo que contiene, tan solo le dices que es un símbolo válido, y que tu sabes que se declara **por completo** en otra parte; que el compilador se puede fiar de ti, que sabes lo que estás haciendo.

Por otra parte, en el `.c` estás *cumpliendo* tu palabra; estas diciendole al compilador lo que realmente **es** la `struct struct _estructura`.

Haciendolo de esta forma, el compilador te permite trabajar **con punteros** a tu `struct _estructura`. **No** te permite trabajar con la estructura en sí, solo con punteros que hagan referencia a ella.

Ese es un método común de *ocultar* los detalles a *programas cliente*; si todas 
 las funcione que usas, en sus argumentos y/o en su valor de retorno, trabajan exclusivamente con punteros, puedes impedir que nadie *toquetee* los datos internos de tu `struct _estructura`: nadie los conoce, ni siquiera el propio compilador.

Comment: la predeclaración no sería `struct _estructura;` ¿¿??

Comment: Es válido también como `typedef struct _estructura estructura`; por lo menos desde el 11, en el 99 no lo recuerdo, pero me suena que también.

Comment: Gracias. Desconocía esa información :)